# Saving Multiple Data Entries into CoreData

Tags: core-data, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to populate my entity in CoreData for a new app.  I made a new function named initializeDB() which sets up new values for the entity and then calls the save() function (within a do try block of course).  However it turns out that only the last entity is actually saved. I'm curious as to know why this is the case.  I know that only the last one is saved since I do a fetch and only see that the last one is returned.

```
        date = myTimeZoneDateFormatter1.dateFromString("2016-02-03")!
        entity.setValue("3.1", forKey: "distanceOfRun")
        entity.setValue(date, forKey: "dateOfRun")
        do{
            try moc.save()
            print("save was successful")
        }
        catch{

            print("Entry was not saved")        }

        date = myTimeZoneDateFormatter1.dateFromString("2016-02-05")!
        entity.setValue("3.1", forKey: "distanceOfRun")
        entity.setValue(date, forKey: "dateOfRun")
        do{
            try moc.save()
            print("save was successful")
        }
        catch{

            print("Entry was not saved")        }

        date = myTimeZoneDateFormatter1.dateFromString("2016-02-07")!
        entity.setValue("3", forKey: "distanceOfRun")
        entity.setValue(date, forKey: "dateOfRun")
        do{
            try moc.save()
            print("save was successful")
        }
        catch{

            print("Entry was not saved")        }
```

Any help in trying to understand this would make me very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are re-saving the same object attributes each time you make `save()`. You should create a new entity for each object with this method:

```
let newobject = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("my_entity", inManagedObjectContext: context)
date = myTimeZoneDateFormatter1.dateFromString("2016-02-03")!
newobject.setValue("3.1", forKey: "distanceOfRun")
newobject.setValue(date, forKey: "dateOfRun")
```

And then save the context again.

Comment: ahh i see, so in effect, i'm not making any new "rows" but in fact just editing the same one? @thxou

Comment: That's exactly what is happening

Comment: but don't you have to do a fetch first before you're able to edit?

Comment: No, they don't need to be stored for you to modify them. Managed objects stays in memory until you save the context in which they were created, so you can even discard the creation or changes in objects if you want.

Comment: see that's where i'm confused. after setting each value i did save the context (moc.save())

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to, you can call `moc.save()` just once at the end of the code that creates the managed objects.